# Mysql bulk delete using "not in"

Tags: mysql, bulk, sql-delete

Anybody can help me with this mysql query:

```
delete from generic__campaings_included where dealer_id not in ('2,3,4') and campaing_id = '1'
```

When I execute this query I didn't get normal result. Except 2 (dealer_id) all rows deleted.

How can I use "not in" with "and" operator?

Comment: It really does help to run a `select` first, to check if you got the 'where' clause right (or even if you got it at all), if you are unsure. Actually, it pays to do it every time.

Comment: @shylent +1 - It also pays to use transaction control so you can `ROLLBACK` if you mess up.

Answer (score 3):

Should it not be this without single quotes?

```
delete from generic__campaings_included where dealer_id not in (2,3,4) and campaing_id = 1
```

or this if the columns are string

```
delete from generic__campaings_included where dealer_id not in ('2','3','4') and campaing_id = '1'
```

You deleted rows where `dealer_id <> '2,3,4'` (that is, a string literal rather than one of 2, 3, or 4)